# IntelliJ, synchronize files after grunt build

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, gruntjs

I am using Grunt to compile our Javascript into a single file, app.js. I am using Grunt inside of intelliJ via the grunt window to fire off a watch that will compile on change.

When a change is made, the grunt task runs and the files are compiled. Next I blur intelliJ, to update the resources on the tomcat server and refresh the browser.

The change never makes it to the tomcat server because intellij doesn't catch that the files have been updated via grunt.

For example: I can make a change and then open the newly compiled app.js file and see the change has not been applied. If I update resources in the project explorer I see the change, and can update it on the tomcat server via frame deactivation.

Is there a way to keep intelliJ synchronized after a grunt build/task fired from a watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out IntelliJ 14 has a bug with registered watch tasks in grunt.

When you run watch via a registered task IntelliJ won't synchronize the files after each run.

If you run watch directly everything should work as expected.

This functionality is fixed in the next version of IntelliJ.

You can follow my conversation on you track here
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14876